# Data of last user is active after another login React Native

Tags: react-native

The problem is pretty simple, but I cannot find a solution to fix this.

I'm testing the login feature with the API I made, the API works fine, but this is a problem with react-native.

After I logout and then log back in with another user, the data of the last user persists in my `HomeScreen.js`

After I refresh the app, the app of course loads the data of the new logged-in User. I'm not sure how its possible to "re-run" the `ComponentDidMount()` or what I actually have to do.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

P.S: If any code is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Store the data coming from the API in a state and at logout function call empty the state using the setState function.

Comment: If you need to re-run the logic in ComponentDidMount you can use ComponentDidUpdate for that

Comment: The problem is that I'm logging out from another screen.

Comment: You can use Redux if you want to fix this problem. It is more better if you can dispatch an action at logout to initialState. @DanielLogvin